# Get Entity key in NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to get the entity using entity key. How to do it?
for this i get the entity using id.
like this Model.get_by_id().
But when i open this entity in the console. its path is something like this.

```
> http://localhost:8000/datastore/edit/entity_key
```

[image]

According to this image the URL to this entity is

```
> http://localhost:8000/datastore/edit/ag1kZXZ-eWFhcmluZWVkcicLEghSZWxpZ2lvbiIFaGluZHUMCxIHU3R1ZGVudBiAgICAgMDvCgw
```

I wanted entity to be opened in new tab to see it in UI.
Strange there is no tag for NDB!!!

Comment: Are you wondering why the "Entity Key" value is displayed as a string, yet an entity key is an object? I sure am...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the [`urlsafe()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_urlsafe) representation of your Key. You can [`construct`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Constructors) a Key by using this representation and then retrieving the actual entity using the [`Key.get()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_get):

```
 entity_db = ndb.Key('ag1kZXZ-eWFhcm...').get()
```

Comment: In this scenario I had the key in the string format so, i have to make key using. urlsafe_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=<entity_key>) and then urlsafe_key.get(). @Lipis thanks.